# Excel 2013: How to adjust the leader lines

Tags: excel

I have a [graph](http://tinypic.com/r/4ugqj4/8) in Excel '13 (stack line with markers) for each of the 'markers', there is a corresponding data label. These 'data labels' are pointing to the marker via a *Leader Line*.

I would like to be able to make the Leader Lines distances all the same, and also most of them vertical. I tried to manually do it, but wasn't too good at it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This goes into the "too hard" basket. Neither the Excel interface nor the Excel Object Model offers any hooks to position data labels at a specific location.

You can record a macro and then drag the labels into the desired position. The code will show something like

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Select
Selection.Left = 125.457
Selection.Top = 130.327
```

... but what that relates to and which coordinates constitute a vertical line is a mathematical exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Use snap to grid option in Page Layout>>Align. If it helps, adjust the column width to 2.14 so the cells become a square grid.